# Print PDF as handout

Tags: linux, pdf, printing, layout

I'd like to print a PDF presentation in the following layout:

[image: laouyt]

Is there any tool to achieve this layout? Unfortunately, the presentation is only available as PDF (i.e. there is no PowerPoint, OpenOffice or TeX file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done using the [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) CLI tool (included in the Ubuntu repository) and *either* directly in the standard PDF reader Evince, or using [PDFjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam), which requires a LaTeX installation, though. In Debian Sid, PDFjam is currently contained in the `texlive-extra-utils` package.

The idea is similar in both cases. With only PDFtk and Evince:

1. Create `lines.pdf` which is a (landscape) PDF that consists of line guides for writing.
2. Burst the handout into single pages using `pdftk`.
3. Create a new PDF where every odd page is a sequential page from the handout, and every even page is an instance of `lines.pdf`.
4. Open the PDF in Evince and choose to print several pages per sheet (6, in landscape mode).

Here is a quick attempt that I could get to work like this. Note that it assumes that the input file is in landscape mode, as is usually the case for presentations. My `lines.pdf` was created with Inkscape in seconds (A4, landscape, create a textbox that fills the entire canvas, size 100, fill with underscores).

Save the script as e.g. `handout.sh`, make it executable and call it with a PDF file as only argument.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
usage() {
    cat <<-USAGE 1>&2
    usage: ${0##*/} [FILE]
    USAGE
    exit 1
}

[ $# -ne 1 ] && usage

if ! TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d); then
    printf 'error: could not create tempdir, aborting.\n' 1>&2
    exit 2
fi
# Clean everything up after closing Evince, or if the script is aborted.
trap 'rm -rf "$TMPDIR"' EXIT

LINES="$HOME/anteckningar/su-handout/lines.pdf"

HANDOUT="$TMPDIR/handout.pdf"

pdftk "$1" burst output "$TMPDIR/p%04d.pdf"

# Create PDF argument list with lines spliced in at every even position.
for p in $TMPDIR/*.pdf; do
    pdfs="$pdfs $p $LINES"
done

pdftk $pdfs cat output "$HANDOUT"
# Open Evince and print the file using wanted settings.
evince "$HANDOUT"
```

---

Using PDFjam, the solution is even simpler for the user. We still need `lines.pdf` as above, and we can modify the script to:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
usage() {
    cat <<-USAGE 1>&2
    usage: ${0##*/} [FILE]
    USAGE
    exit 1
}

[ $# -ne 1 ] && usage

if ! TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d); then
    printf 'error: could not create tempdir, aborting.\n' 1>&2
    exit 2
fi
# Clean everything up after closing Evince, or if the script is aborted.
trap 'rm -rf "$TMPDIR"' EXIT

LINES="$HOME/anteckningar/su-handout/lines.pdf"

HANDOUT="$TMPDIR/handout.pdf"
HANDOUT_SIXUP="${HANDOUT%.pdf}-6up.pdf"

pdftk "$1" burst output "$TMPDIR/p%04d.pdf"

# Create PDF argument list with lines spliced in at every even position.
for p in $TMPDIR/*.pdf; do
    pdfs="$pdfs $p $LINES"
done

pdftk $pdfs cat output "$HANDOUT"
pdfjam-slides6up --frame false --outfile "$TMPDIR" "$HANDOUT"
evince "$HANDOUT_SIXUP"
```

This opens an Evince session where the PDF is already correctly formatted for direct printing. One could modify this to send the result directly to the printer, but I would rather get the preview in Evince in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) will do this.  Create your slides as a presentation, then print it using 'Document: Handouts' and 'Slides per page: 3' by setting up your Print dialog like this:

[image: LibreOffice Impress print dialog]

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately only the PDF file is available. Do you know any other solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not -- you can import your PDF into LibreOffice Draw, and copy-and-paste each page into Impress, but that's far from optimal for a large document.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how you are producing the presentation. All decent presentation tools will produce **handouts**. This is what you want.

Both Libre Office and Microsoft PowerPoint will do this.

In your case, you've now clarified that you have the slides ONLY in PDF format and you want to add space for notes.

The easy way is to use a decent PDF reader tool (not sure you can do this in the Adobe reader as I never use it). I use PDF-XChange Editor and I can print the example file with auto-rotate and auto-centre turned **off**, this gives the following layout:

[image]

So you get space below the slide to write in, not quite the same but very easy to achieve. You could probably play with it further to get closer to your example. You could also get a lined note area by using either a background image or background page template.

Going further than that would require you to extract each page from the PDF and re-composite, probably more work than really warranted.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately only the PDF file is available. Do you know any other solution?

Comment: What layout is the presentation currently in? Let us know and we can give some more guidance.

Comment: It is a PDF exported from some unknown software. A real life example is available [here](https://github.com/reedr/reedr/blob/master/slides/efsf2014-whatsapp-scaling.pdf) (I can't upload my original PDF as I'm not sure whether I'm allowed to publish it)

Answer (score 0):

Open the PDF in LibreOffice. It should open in LibreOffice Draw.

Start an empty Impress presentation. Change the page size of the presentation to match that in the PDF (match the actual paper size in millimeters/inches, not just aspect ratio).

Select all the slides in Draw. Copy (Ctrl-C).

Go to Impress. Paste (Ctrl-V).

Delete the blank slide from the LibreOffice template.

Hopefully you now have a non-editable presentation you can print.